# Eclipselink throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I'm having problems with some `ConcurrentModificationException` in a code of an application:

```
   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-2004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConcurrencyException
Exception Description: A signal was attempted before wait() on ConcurrencyManager. This normally means that an attempt was made to 
commit or rollback a transaction before it was started, or to rollback a transaction twice.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConcurrencyException.signalAttemptedBeforeWait(ConcurrencyException.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.releaseReadLock(ConcurrencyManager.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.releaseReadLock(CacheKey.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1022)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:933)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.getAndCloneCacheKeyFromParent(UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.getFromIdentityMap(UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3920)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3874)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.buildUnitofWorkCloneForPartObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.buildCloneForPartObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkQueryValueHolder.buildCloneFor(UnitOfWorkQueryValueHolder.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:88)
```

Analising the code, I've found the class responsible for provide the EntityManager:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import weblogic.javaee.CallByReference;

@Stateful (name = "DAOFactoryRemoteBean", mappedName = "DAOFactoryRemoteBean")
@CallByReference
public class DAOFactoryRemoteImplBean implements DAOFactoryRemoteBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "server_unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    private static String getDAOName(Class<?> classeEntidade) {
        String result = classeEntidade.getName()
            .replace("org.networkmap.server.bean.",
            "org.networkmap.server.bean.dao.");
        result = result.concat("DAO");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDAO(Class<?> entityClass) {
        NetworkmapDao result = null;

        try {
           result = (NetworkmapDao) Class.forName(getDAOName(entityClass))
               .newInstance();
           result.setEntityManager(em);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

There's a lot of EJB's that calls the `getDAO` method. And a lot of users of the app. I guess it may cause concurrent problems indeed.

I don't have a good expertise with that, but according some search on internet, it seems like there's no good practice on that code, considering that `EntityManger` is not thread safe. I'm stuck with this problem :(

The app uses the EclipseLink v2.4.2 API, running on a Weblogic 10.3.5 over a Solaris O.S. And there's only one persitent unit declared on `persistence.xml`.

Please someone help me.

Comment: The code path that's going to be relevant here is the specific entry point into the EJB (some method), and how that method directly and indirectly accesses the transaction manager (hint: it shouldn't) & entity manager.  Also enough of the stack trace to identify the point in your code (presumably it will be on the code path already discussed) where the exception is actually triggered.  None of that is provided here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the same EntityManager with different threads?  If so, then don't do that.

Otherwise, please include the full exception stack trace.

What does, "result.setEntityManager(em);" do?

Comment: `NetworkmapDao` is a abstract class that all DAOs extends. `setEntityManager(em)` sets to each DAO a reference to entity manager. Then what's the best approach for the case having many threads?